# How can I make a Roll20 macro that shows different text depending on the result of a die roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, roll20

I would like to roll for the random Chaos Bolt (first level spell) damage type, which is variable.

In play, I have to roll `1d8` and as a result I get the `damage type` of the spell:

I guess it should be something like:

```
&{template:default} {{name=Damage Type}} 
{{[[1d8]]|acid|cold|fire|force|lightning|poison|psychic|thunder}}
```

The result should be:

- Damage Type: cold

Nice to Have:

- if you hover over cold you see '2'

Comment: Note that Chaos Bolt has you roll *2*d8, and you can pick either one to determine the damage type.

Comment: @GreySage Thanks, I will add that to the macro

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to include the answer (or rather, the macro you arrived at based on the answer). Instead, you should leave it as a comment on the accepted answer, or as an answer itself if you feel it is sufficiently distinct from the existing answer. In general, answer content doesn't belong in the question; it makes the post confusing to read and discourages future answers.

Comment: Related: [How can I set up a Roll20 macro to roll certain additional dice depending on the results of an initial die roll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139488/how-can-i-set-up-a-roll20-macro-to-roll-certain-additional-dice-depending-on-the)

Comment: @V2Blast It is related, but the other thread did not produce an answer.

Comment: @Torsten: I'm aware. The previous comment that linked to it just mostly made a point that was already addressed (it linked the related question as an afterthought to that point), so I deleted that comment and reposted the link to the related question as its own comment. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is something you should use a [Rollable Table](https://wiki.roll20.net/Collections#Rollable_Tables) for. Create a table with 8 entries, one for each damage type. You could call it "Chaos-Bolt". Then modify your macro above to:

```
&{template:default} {{name=Chaos bolt}}{{damage type = [[1t[Chaos-Bolt]]]}}
```

If you want the actual number to show, just write the entries as:

```
Acid (1)
Cold (2)
...
```

[image: Rollable Table]

The results will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Great to see you drop by again, thanks Keith!  I have a shadow sorcerer in the game I DM who would like this.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks a lot. That one works great.